# AEM Osgi Sling Model @PostConstruct never called

Tags: annotations, osgi, adobe, aem, sling

I am having an issue with the javax.annotation.PostConstruct annotation in my Sling model.

My html file that uses my model:

```
<div data-sly-use="com.company.platform.component.general.textblockvalidator.TextBlockValidatorModel" data-sly-unwrap />
```

Model:

```
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Model(adaptables = org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource.class)
public class TextBlockValidatorModel {

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println();
    }

    public String getValidate(){
        return "This works";
    }
}
```

I can call the getter from my sightly file but I never seem to enter my @PostConstruct init() method.

IntelliJ does give me a warning on the annotation but I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

[image]

Sling-model-packages:

```
<Sling-Model-Packages>
   ...
   com.asadventure.platform.component
   ...
</Sling-Model-Packages>
```

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the AEM version?

Comment: i guess you can't add `@PostConstruct` annotation on `init()` method.

Comment: @i.net we are using version 6.1

Comment: @VAr how come so?

Comment: FWIW, the intellij warning can be ignored as long as your dependency scope of packages is set to provided and is applicable. I think that's just a warning in intellij design for provided dependencies

Comment: Are you sure that your model is actually created using sling models? Please check if you have your package registered in pom.xml maven-bundle-plugin configuration you should have something like this `<Sling-Model-Packages>your.package</Sling-Model-Packages>`

Comment: @rzasap how do you mean? I have annotated my class using: @Model(adaptables = org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource.class). Isn't this enough?

Comment: I have edited my previous comment

Comment: `@PostConstruct` annotation can be used to add methods which are invoked upon completion of all injections.
Generally we implement the `init()` and `destroy()` methods which are directly related to the `start()`,`stop()` methods of the activator.
The DependencyManager, which is passed as an argument to these methods, can then be used to define the services and dependencies.
have a look at [sling documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#postconstruct-methods) which states 
`@PostConstruct
methods to call upon model option creation (only for model classes)`

Comment: The class is part of my Sling-Model-Packages, check my update :)

Comment: I do not know if this is a valid declaration:`data-sly-use="com.company.platform.component.general.textblockvalidator.TextBlockValidatorModel"`. Try with some valid name, for example: `data-sly-use.modelName="com.company.platform.component.general.textblockvalidator.TextBlockValidatorModel"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, check your Sling Model has been registered correctly by looking for your class in this web page: 
http://localhost:4502/system/console/status-adapters

If it isn't listed there, you most likely have not specified the `<Sling-Model-Packages>` property of the `maven-bundle-plugin`.

I would also try changing the access modifier for the `init` method to `protected` or `public`.

**UPDATE:**

I've created a sample project for AEM 6.1 demonstrating the use of the @PostConstruct annotation.

The Sling Model class:

```
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class SampleModel {

    private boolean postContructCalled = false;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.postContructCalled = true;
    }

    public boolean isPostContructCalled() {
        return this.postContructCalled;
    }
}
```

And a simple HTL component:

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="com.github.mickleroy.models.SampleModel">
    <p>@PostConstruct was called: ${model.postContructCalled}</p>
</sly>
```

Please take note of the use of the `data-sly-use` directive - you need to provide a model name.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, you should not be adding `javax.annotation-api` as a dependency as it is part of the JDK.

Full source available here: https://github.com/mickleroy/sling-models-sample

Comment: My model is listed:


Adaptable: org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource
Providing Bundle: org.apache.sling.models.impl
Available Adapters:
 * com.asadventure.platform.component.general.textblockvalidator.TextBlockValidatorModel. My package is also specified under sling-model-packages.

Comment: That's good. Then just try changing the init() method to protected or even public. I don't see any other reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Changed it into protected and public, didn't change. Could it be that @PostConstruct just isn't recognised?

Comment: I've used the @PostConstruct annotation many times, it's definitely recognised. May I ask how you are checking that the init() method was called? Are you remote debugging and setting a break point?

Comment: Yes I am remote debugging, I have a private variable in my class set to "no" and within the @PostConstruct I set it to "yes". This variable is returned by a getter that is called in my sightly html. (break point is never "executed" and getter always return 'no')

Comment: I just created a working project for 6.1 that demonstrates the use of @PostConstruct. I'll put it up on GitHub tomorrow. You can also check this project which makes use of a Sling Model too (look for "PokeStop" class): https://github.com/mickleroy/aem-pokego-lure-client

Comment: Thank you :) I'm going to take a look at it. Followed you on GitHub so I should get a notification when you push your new repo.

Comment: By the way, I have an <Embed-Dependency>javax.annotation-api</Embed-Dependency> using version 1.2

Comment: You shouldn't need that at all. Take that out as well as any dependency to "javax.annotation-api" you may have added to your POM.

Comment: Even if I am not using the uber-jar? Because how could I use the annotations without the dependency?

Comment: The "javax.annotation" library comes with the JDK.

Comment: PS: you really should be using the UberJar, it'll make your life much easier ;)

Comment: So this shouldn't be provided to the OSGI container? I am going to convert my project into using the UberJar.

Comment: Converting our massive project into using the uber-jar seems to be too much work. I'll accept your answer as the correct one, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this that the above did not resolve, the issue for me was that I did not include the javax.annotation-api dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Once I added this in the parent pom, and its inclusion in the core pom, @PostConstruct worked just fine.

**Update:**

The reason I had to do this was because of my inclusion of `jersey-client`, which requires its own version of `javax.annotation-api`. Since my first rendition of this answer, I have found I needed to separate `jersey-client` and its dependencies into a separate bundle project. This allows both Jersey and `@PostConstruct` to work at the same time.

Just adding the dependency as the answer shows above caused issues with dependency clashes between Jersey's version of `javax.annotation-api` and AEM's version (Felix's version) of `javax.annotation-api`.

Comment: this helped me big time indirectly. I was using Google Cloud API, this used javax.annotation was was breaking my slingModel. So I ended up breaking my bundle in two. one that contained my project code and sling models two that contained only Google API code and it's dependencies. Both work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your class is being initialized by the Java Use provider instead of adapting the current resource or request.

In sightly, when you use data-sly-use, it tries several things to obtain an object (I cant recall the order):

- get an Osgi service with that name
- use the AEM Java USE Api
- Adapt the current request / resource into your model class (your desired case)
- simply treat the class as a Java Pojo and instantiate it (post construct is not called, injection wont be done).

I've seen several cases where the injection or postconstruct methods of the sling models fails and sightly defaults to the java Use provider. If this happens what you describe happens. You have an object of the right class, but no injection happened and no post construct was called.

My recommendation is to careful check the logs, you should see an error if this is the case. Also, you can install the `Scripting HTL Sling Models Use Provider` which will propagate any error creating the sling model, making the problem obvious.

Comment: The weird thing is that Injection DOES happen, I am able to inject OSGI services.

Comment: excuse my meddling in this conversation and my ignorance --- could you please tell how to install "Scripting HTL/Sightly Sling Models Use Provider" on AEM 6.1? 

i seem to be facing the same issue - my sling models are not registered, PostConstruct annotated method is not called, and looks like the model class is being instantiated by JavaUseProvider which was throwing NullPointerExceptions for injected variables.

Comment: @saasira easiest is to embed the bundle ( http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.models.provider ) in an AEM package (below a 'install' folder).

Comment: thank you @santiagozky; i tried that but still sling models are not registered.

SightlyJava_component.render(SightlyJava_component.java:60) where it is failing with null pointer because osgi service was not injected. not only that postconstruct method is also not invoked. can we force sightly to use model provider else fail with exception rather than use javause provider?

Comment: @Saasira that is what the provider does. it uses the ModelFactory service instead of adaptTo to instantiate the model. The ModelFactory propagates exceptions (adaptTo never does this).